# Swift Mapkit center of view

Tags: ios, swift, camera, mapkit

Are there some way to move the figure (current location, aka `blue dot`) to the `center` of the map field (and not the center of the entire map)? Even thought it follows the figure

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.014, 0.014)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Change the `MKCoordinateSpanMake` if you want to modify the zooming.

Comment: I've tried it now, but doesn't seem to work as I thougt, the map moves to somewhere in the sea, but does not follow at all. Here is how I used the code, did I do wrong? 

`    func setRegionMap() {
        let location = theMap.centerCoordinate as CLLocationCoordinate2D
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.414, 0.014)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        theMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }`

Comment: @VictorKrusenstråhle, I have created an example project that you can work from that shows the example above. Download it from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TR9xoKqvZNcjJtblNXbTUxOTg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: But what do I do if I want to move the so called "center" up to the top of the mapkit?